# org-mode Beamer export: can't change format of title page and TOC

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, pdf, beamer

I have an org file that I use to create a pdf with `org-beamer-export-to-pdf`. The file has things like this at the top:

```
#+TITLE: Training
#+OPTIONS: H:2 toc:1 num:t
#+LATEX_CLASS: beamer
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [presentation]
#+BEAMER_THEME: Montpellier

# No Navigation Symbols
#+LaTeX:\setbeamercovered{transparent}
#+LaTeX:\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %remove navigation symbols
#+LaTeX:\setbeamercovered{invisible} %No transparent layers
```

Along with some color configurations, too. These changes (for exmaple, getting rid of the navigation symobls) work on all the body slides. However nothing I do affects the appearance of the Title Page or the Table of Contents.

Even explicitly setting something like

```
#+LaTeX:\setbeamercolor*{title page}{fg=mycolor, bg=myothercolor}
```

has no effect on the title page. This holds true for `titlelike` `title` `subtitle` `author` or `section in toc` or `subsection in toc` and so forth.

Why can't I configure the 1st two slides of my presentation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `#+LaTeX:` you should try `#+BEAMER_HEADER:` for all beamer specific configuration lines.

For example: `#+BEAMER_HEADER: \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}` removes navigation symbols in all slides including title page and toc.

Comment: Outstanding! This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `\documentclass[usepdftitle=false]{beamer}` option with `#+LATEX_CLASS:`? That would at least allow for customizing the title page to your liking, possibly.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are suggesting. I tried `#+LATEX_CLASS: \documentclass[usepdftitle=false]{beamer}` and running org-beamer-export-to-pdf resulted in `unknown latex class`

Comment: My bad, I didn't bother to check out the code myself. Org-beamer isn't exactly one to one with latex obviously, there are some funky conversion rules/behaviors. Try `#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [usepdftitle=false]`. Make sure this command comes after the previous Options one. I'm not a pro with org-to-beamer so no promises on this one, it's very much test and see approach for my own stuff.